# Example of latest android facebook sdk-4.8.2 login and get users details

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I had made an app 5 months ago.

In this app, I had used Facebook sdk API version v2.3. All is working good. But now I have change the app package name. So I have to create a new Facebook developer account. In this account, the API version is v2.5 and the Facebook sdk version is 4.8.2.

So now I am not able to get the user profile details anymore (like first name, last name, email, gender etc.). Can anyone please help me with the new changes to the sdk and how to integrate with the new version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Use this code for get details.

Request.executeMeRequestAsync(Session.getActiveSession(),
                        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                    Response response) {

                                if (user != null) {

                                    Bundle params = new Bundle();
                                    params.putString("fields",
                                            "cover,first_name,gender,last_name,email");
                                    new Request(Session.getActiveSession(),
                                            "me", params, HttpMethod.GET,
                                            new Request.Callback() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onCompleted(
                                                        Response response) {}

                                                }
                                            }).executeAsync();
```